# iphone:how to archive files while using crash reports in iphone device

Tags: iphone, xcode

In xcode when we archive the applicatton binary and .dSYM files it automatically create its symbolicate..but how to create that archive files and where that converted symbolic file is stored?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Xcode 3.2.2 introduces the “Build and Archive” command to aid in this process. When you use the Build and Archive command, Xcode will gather the application binary and the .dSYM containing symbol information together and store them in a location in your home folder. You can find all of your archived applications in the Xcode Organizer under the Archived Applications section in Ad Hoc

so connect your device - go to xcode organizer - click Device - Device Logs - It will symbolicate crashes for you

Hope this Helps!

Answer (score 1):

open Xcode, select "Organizer" from the "Window" menu, and find your device. You'll see a crash log tab.